# How to exclude duplicate rows when joining a table with itself

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, outer-join

Here's a sample table to help illustrate my problem:

```
mysql> select * from test;
+----+--------------+--------+
| id | type         | siteid |
+----+--------------+--------+
|  1 | First Visit  |    100 |
|  2 | Second Visit |    100 |
|  3 | First Visit  |    300 |
|  4 | First Visit  |    400 |
|  5 | Second Visit |    500 |
|  6 | Second Visit |    600 |
+----+--------------+--------+
```

I'm trying to join the table upon itself, to pull together rows that have the same siteid value.  Here's my attempt:

```
mysql> select * from test T1
    -> LEFT OUTER JOIN test T2 on T1.siteid = T2.siteid and T1.id <> T2.id;
+----+--------------+--------+------+--------------+--------+
| id | type         | siteid | id   | type         | siteid |
+----+--------------+--------+------+--------------+--------+
|  1 | First Visit  |    100 |    2 | Second Visit |    100 |
|  2 | Second Visit |    100 |    1 | First Visit  |    100 |
|  3 | First Visit  |    300 | NULL | NULL         |   NULL |
|  4 | First Visit  |    400 | NULL | NULL         |   NULL |
|  5 | Second Visit |    500 | NULL | NULL         |   NULL |
|  6 | Second Visit |    600 | NULL | NULL         |   NULL |
+----+--------------+--------+------+--------------+--------+
```

This is basically the result I'm looking for, except for the 1st 2 rows.  I'd like to eliminate one of those.  So, I tried the following:

```
mysql> select * from test T1
    -> LEFT OUTER JOIN test T2 on T1.siteid = T2.siteid and T1.id <> T2.id
    -> GROUP BY T1.siteid;
+----+--------------+--------+------+--------------+--------+
| id | type         | siteid | id   | type         | siteid |
+----+--------------+--------+------+--------------+--------+
|  1 | First Visit  |    100 |    2 | Second Visit |    100 |
|  3 | First Visit  |    300 | NULL | NULL         |   NULL |
|  4 | First Visit  |    400 | NULL | NULL         |   NULL |
|  5 | Second Visit |    500 | NULL | NULL         |   NULL |
|  6 | Second Visit |    600 | NULL | NULL         |   NULL |
+----+--------------+--------+------+--------------+--------+
```

This is exactly the output I'm looking for.  However, I come to learn this isn't the standard way to use GROUP BY, and the above statement fails on ORACLE, giving me a

**General SQL error.
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression**

Can anyone offer some help on how to get the results like the last table and that works with ORACLE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just remove a single character from your query and it will get the job done... (replace "<>" with "<"):

```
select * from test T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN test T2 on T1.siteid = T2.siteid and T1.id < T2.id
```